# Is it possible to use a DbContext without connecting to a database?

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, entity-framework-4.1

I am using Entity Framework Code-First in my application and I am going to unit test some services. I have Repository and Unit of Work patterns all built and I'm trying to figure out the best way to fake these objects for my tests. I could certainly create completely fake Repository and Unit of Work classes for my tests, but I'd like to avoid re-implementing many of the features of the DbContext (for instance, management of related objects, change tracking, etc.) in my fakes.

I really want everything that DbContext does except:

1. Attempting to retrieve anything from the underlying data store.
2. Attempting to write anything to the underlying data store.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Fakes of your repositories as long as they are implementating appropriate interfaces shouldn't require any reimplementation of your context.  At most they only need to contain an in memory list of their associated entity type(s).  Alternatively use a mocking framework such as Moq to create the fake implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server Compact Edition database for your unit/integration test. You can create a CE database through a database initializer. This database will have a similar structure to your database and EF API will work without any modifications.

However if you have used stored procedures or database specific features then you are out of luck testing those features.